# Parsing the Data Returned from a javascript JSON call

Tags: javascript, json

This code is on a Button onClick event:

```
function loadJSONData(url) {
  var headID = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];
  var newScript = document.createElement('script');
      newScript.type = 'text/javascript';
      newScript.src = url;
  headID.appendChild(newScript);
}

loadJSONData('http://api.lemonfree.com/listings?key=2806cdf10605dc9598b1cf3a2387acb7&make=HUMMER&model=H2&zip=80901&distance=100&per_page=25&sortby=Price&sortdir=ASC&year_from=2005&year_to=2008&format=json&callback=processJSONData');
```

---

This code is in the Load JavaScript area

```
function processJSONData(data){
  alert( "Id: " + data.response.requestType );

  console.log( 'Id:' );
  console.log( data.response.requestType );
}
```

---

When I press the Button the onclick event fires and the below JSON data is returned.

The problem is that I cannot figure out how to reference the data with it.

I have tried everthing that I can think of to access the data elements.

```
data.response.requestType,
data.response.result[0].id

response.requestType,
response.result[0].id
```

etc.

www.jsonlint.com validates the returned data as valid json also
jsonviewer.stack.hu also validates the returned data as valid json.

Any HELP would be greatly appreciated.

Mark

---

If you enter this into your browser you will receive the data that is returned

http://api.lemonfree.com/listings?key=2806cdf10605dc9598b1cf3a2387acb7&make=HUMMER&model=H2&zip=80901&distance=100&per_page=25&sortby=Price&sortdir=ASC&year_from=2005&year_to=2008&format=json&callback=processJSONData

Comment: have you used json.parse to get the object?

Comment: NO - how would I add that to my existing code?

Answer (score 0):

Your `loadJSONData` function actually uses [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP), so you don't need to parse anything at all - `data` would just be the object.

Only the lemonfree api does not seem to support JSONP, the ressource you linked to is plain JSON - the callback "padding" is missing. And the [SOP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) prevents you from accessing it directly via Ajax, so you'll need to use some kind of proxy.

Comment: Bergi - how can I add the "padding" to it?

Comment: You can't. The webserver must do it. Or is `api.lemonfree.com` under your control?